# Python multiprocessing.Process behaves non deterministic

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

The following code shows a simple multiprocessing.Process pipeline with a shared dictionary of lists and a task queue for different consumers:

```python
import multiprocessing

class Consumer(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, task_queue, result_dict):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.task_queue = task_queue
        self.result_dict = result_dict

    def run(self):
        proc_name = self.name
        while True:
            next_task = self.task_queue.get()
            if next_task is None:
                # Poison pill means shutdown
                print('%s: Exiting' % proc_name)
                self.task_queue.task_done()
                break
            print('%s: %s' % (proc_name, next_task))

            # Do something with the next_task
            l = self.result_dict[5]
            l.append(3)
            self.result_dict[5] = l
            # alternative, but same problem
            #self.result_dict[5] += [3]

            self.task_queue.task_done()
        return

def provide_tasks(tasks, num_worker):
    low = [ 
        ['w1', 'w2'],
        ['w3'],
        ['w4', 'w5']
    ]
    for el in low:
        tasks.put(el)
    # Add a poison pill for each worker
    for i in range(num_worker):
        tasks.put(None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_worker = 3
    tasks = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()

    results = manager.dict()
    lists = [manager.list() for i in range(1, 11)]
    for i in range(1, 11):
        results[i] = lists[i - 1]

    worker = [Consumer(tasks, results) for i in range(num_worker)]
    for w in worker:
        w.start()

    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=provide_tasks, args=(tasks,num_worker))
    p.start()
    # Wait for all of the tasks to finish
    p.join()
    print(results)
```

When you run this example with Python3.x you will receive different outputs for the results dict. I actually expect the results dict to look like

```
{1: [], 2: [], 3: [], 4: [], 5: [3, 3, 3], 6: [], 7: [], 8: [], 9: [], 10: []}
```

But for some executions it looks like this:

```
{1: [], 2: [], 3: [], 4: [], 5: [3, 3], 6: [], 7: [], 8: [], 9: [], 10: []}
```

Can someone explain me this behavior? Why is somethings a number missing?

**Updated solution approach according to the proposed answer:**

```
if next_task is None:
    with lock:
        self.result_dict.update(self.local_dict)
        [...]
```

Where lock is a `manager.Lock()` and self.local_dict is a `defaultdict(list)`.

**Moved lock according to the answer comment. Also added a version that doesn't work with the lock.**

```
# Works
with lock:
    l = self.result_dict[x]
    l.append(3)
    self.result_dict[x] = l
self.task_queue.task_done()

# Doesn't work. Even if I move the lock out of the loop. 
for x in range(1, 10):
    with lock:
        l = self.result_dict[x]
        l.append(3)
        self.result_dict[x] = l
```

In order to get the second example to work, we need to call `join` on all worker too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting a local copy of the list, modifying it, and reassigning it to the manager dict is not an atomic operation, thus creating a race condition where an append operation can get "lost".

Described in [this python bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue9801%C2%A0%C2%A0opened).

```
l = self.result_dict[5]  # <-- race begins
l.append(3)
self.result_dict[5] = l  # <-- race ends
```

Comment: So, I understand the root cause to be this: *"Storing a proxy into a proxied object and then accessing the proxy returns a copy of the object itself and not the stored proxy."* ([source](http://bugs.python.org/issue6766))

Comment: Makes sense to me. Quite a big pitfall. I've updated my question with a solution approach: Storing the values in a local dictionary and update the shared dict only once with a common lock. However, same behavior as before. I assumed the lock will block the resource for the other processes and once it it free the others update their local results to the common shared dictionary. Do you see the problem? Do you have a working solution to overcome the issue?

Comment: Deferring the update until the poison pill comes should only aggravate this because the duration of the race increases. Try using the lock to protect those 3 lines I mention in my answer: `with lock: get; append; set`. That way, they become an atomic operation. (Depending on how often your workers do that, it'll incur some locking overhead.)

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, this is quite a frequently executed operation in my workers.  So this could be a problem. That's the reason why I've moved the lock to the poison pill branch. I assumed that it is only executed once the worker is finished which reduces the lock overhead. I don't see the problem here. If the first worker finishes, he will lock the shared dict and update the values. Same goes for the other workers. So I expect the output of every local dict merged in the shared dict. Where is the problem?Do you see another solution to overcome the lock overhead in the **non** poison pill branch.

Comment: I've also added a version with a for loop that doesn't work - even with the lock. The lock is quite a problem since all of my workers write really often to this dictionary.

Comment: Okay, locking in poison pill branch should work and minimize overhead. But I don't see why the lock in a loop shouldn't work the same as without a loop. I'll have to investigate that.

Comment: I found the problem (Yay!). Just waiting for the Process is not enough, because it's like just waiting for the producer. Once all tasks have been distributed it will print the result. This totally ignores if the worker are finished or not! So we have to add w.join() for each worker too! This might be an obvious finding, but I totally missed it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Very good. I was just about to go debugging it, and I wouldn't have paid attention to that spot :-)